# Search for pattern. Put it in buffer and do sorting using regex ( Notepad++ or cygwin Shell ) or JSFiddle

Tags: regex, shell, notepad++, jsfiddle, regex-group

I'd like to identify certain pattern and move entire lines to a specific part of a file thereby re-arranging the file contents should you say. I prefer a `notepad++` solution but if you think that is too complex then a  `cygwin shell ( awk )`  or `JSfiddle` also works 
 I will  make my point with example below

```
    I have a pattern that is 
"col<variable space>stat<variable space>col ( axx,bvb,ccc) on mr.dan"  (<some word> confidence)
e.g. 
"col  stat  col ( a123,b6949,c4433) on Mr.Randy"  (Low confidence) 
"col         stat       col     ( a1fddf23, b6ff949,c4433 ) on    John.Doe  "  (Low confidence) 
"col     stat   col     ( ax ) on    John.Dane  "  (Ok confidence) 
"col stat col ( axdf,fsdds ) on    Jane.Dame "  (  Fair confidence )
```

**What it should do**

- Get rid of all the quotes , rid of the `(<word> confidence)` part and stick a `";"` at the end of line ( I can manage this part and dont need help here )
- the expression `col ( axdf,fsdds )` of the with pattern

`col\s+(\s*word1\s*,\s*word2\s*,\s*wordN\s*)\s*on\s*word.word\s*`

Above pattern need to be re-arranged so that ones with one word `col ( word)` will come on top , followed by two words  `col ( word1, word2)` and so on in the ascending order of the number of words in `col ( word )` expression 

So out put of the above should be

```
col     stat   col     ( ax ) on    John.Dane  ;    # 1 word in col (word) expr 
col stat col ( axdf,fsdds ) on    Jane.Dame ;     # 2 words in col (word) expr 
col         stat       col     ( a1fddf23, b6ff949,c4433 ) on    John.Doe  ;    ; # 3 words in col (word) expr 
col  stat  col ( a123,b6949,c4433) on Mr.Randy;
```

**What I did** 
I could get the 1st part done using 
`"\s*\((\s*(\w+)*\s*Confidence\))` replace with `;`

I need help with the 2nd part the `col ( word)` expression rearrange.
logical pseudocode for `Notepad++` would be first two isolate the wordlist in each of those column expressions in separate buffers. next you count the number of words in each buffer and then arrange the buffers. based on the buffer arrangement you lineup the expressions.

 Also open to `JsFiddle` or  `Shellscript regex / awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with Notepad++, I suggest to use a script, here an example of Perl script that does the job.

**The whole file is read in memory, it will be a problem if he file is very large.**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

# Read input file in an array
my $file_in = 'file.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file_in or die "unable to open '$file_in': $!";
my @lines = <$fh>;

# Replace last quote until end of line with semicolon and remove quotes
my @unsorted = map { s/"[^"]*$/;/; s/"//g; $_ } @lines; 

# use Schartzian transform for sorting
my @sorted = 
    # remove the number of words
    map  { $_->[0] }
    # sort on number of words
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    # Add number of words
    map  { 
        # list of words inside parenthesis
        my ($words) = $_ =~ /\(([^)]+)\)/;
        # split to have number of words
        my @w = split',', $words;
        # add this number as second element in array
        [$_, scalar @w] 
    }
    @unsorted;

# Write into output file
my $file_out = 'file_out.txt';
open my $fh_out, '>', $file_out or die "unable to open '$file_out': $!";
say $fh_out $_ for @sorted;
```

**Output file:**

```
col     stat   col     ( ax ) on    John.Dane  ;
col stat col ( axdf,fsdds ) on    Jane.Dame ;
col  stat  col ( a123,b6949,c4433) on Mr.Randy;
col         stat       col     ( a1fddf23, b6ff949,c4433 ) on    John.Doe  ;
```